# Deleting a document in monogid after sometime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am working on rails app with mongoid. This is one of model(collection):

```
class Document
 include Mongoid::Document
 include Mongoid::Timestamps
 include Mongoid::Paperclip

 field :time, type: Time
 field :radius, type: Float
 attr_accessible :time,:radius
end
```

The time field contain the actual time when model should be deleted. How can I do that , One idea I have to write a script put that in cron job. But I don't want to create a cron job. Is there any other way I can automate this or any method inside rails model I can define or something inbuilt into rails only. I am surely missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this without cron by using [TTL indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/).

All you need to do is to put a TTL index on that field:

```
db.log.events.ensureIndex( { "time": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } ) // this means that it will expire in 1 hour after the time in the field `time`
```

Comment: Actually I don't think there is a need for using index.I just want to do that as a document is made I want to add that after time (field in hours ) it should get deleted. Any idea the mongoid command I should use.

Comment: @DeependerSingla without an index you will not be able to achieve this. Exactly index is giving you this functionality of deletion after some time. And there is no mongoid command that does this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use delayed_job gem: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

```
document.delay(run_at: time).destroy
```

Comment: Nice Suggestion will try it. currently I initiate a method everytime when a search is made which checks if the document still need to exist or not and if no it delete it. So it does not come into search.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your model to achieve it:

```
index({:time => 1}, {background: true, expire_after_seconds: 0})
```

Also doing the index in the background in case your collection is large. You need an index because to find the items to delete you don't want to have to seek through the whole collection.